# How to represent a double push or double pop operation in push down automata

Tags: pushdown-automata

I want to know the theoretical representation of a double push or a double pop in pda

Answer (score 2):

There are several different definitions of pushdown automata. In the definition I know, every transition pops one stack symbol and pushes an arbitrary number of stack symbols. Thus you cannot "double pop", but you can push more than one element. You can simulate a double pop using $\epsilon$-transitions, but I'll let you figure that out.